# LINQ to SQL query with variable

Tags: sql, variables, view, controller

I imagine this is very simple to solve, but i cant seem to figure it out and searching has not resulted anything meaningful.

**Business Problem:** Just trying to retrieve details from a ADO.NET Entity Data table by passing in a variable to the query.   Whats odd is that when I pass in a symbol take "FB" for vSymbol it works fine, however, when passing a variable, it returns the page with no data.     This is what its passing into the controller.

**View** 
       @Html.ActionLink(item.Symbol, "CompanyDetails", "Companies", new { id = item.Symbol }, null)

Controller

```
   public ActionResult CompanyDetails(string vSymbol)
    {
        var SymbolDetails = from t in db.Companies
                       where t.Symbol == vSymbol
                            select t;
        return View(SymbolDetails);

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do actually? The above looks almost fine for `ActionLink`.

Comment: @MarkWoodward What you mean by `when passing a variable`?

Comment: I have a view that has a list of stocks. If you want to see more detail about one of the stocks, you click on its symbol (hence the html.actionlink).  In theory, that is passed to this actionresult and queries the database for the details.  But whenever I click on it, it loads the page with no data.   (and yes there is data in the table. ;-) ).   But if i put "FB" (for Facebook e.g) in place of vSymbol it works fine.

Comment: I meant passing a parameter (not variable)

Comment: Solved... user fat fingering...